# Foreground Service is getting killed immediately in Android 4.1 ~ 5.1.1 when app is killed

Tags: android, foreground-service

I have a service which is downloading a file in foreground

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int sid){
        this.sid = sid;
        PendingIntent mainIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, MyApplication.mainIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(VuclipPrime.getInstance())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Downloading Video")
                .setContentText("Initiating...")
                .setContentIntent(mainIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build();
        startForeground(mNotificationId, notification);
        if (VideoDownloadManager.currentVideoDownloadTask != null) {
            VideoDownloadManager.currentVideoDownloadTask.start();
        } else {
            stopSelf();
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

When I swipe to kill the app, the service is being stopped as well.
I tried all the existing solutions on StackOverflow, but none are working.
I tried the YouTube app and it does not kill its service. How do I achieve that ? Thanks.

Comment: above 21 use job Sceduler api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to launch a dummy activity in the onTaskRemoved() method of the service which prevents the service from getting killed.
Also finish the DummyActivity immediately after launching.

Check the following code :-

```
package com.your.application.services;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;


public class DownloadService extends Service {
    int mNotificationId = 001;
    Notification notification;
    private int sid;

    public DownloadService() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int sid) {
        this.sid = sid;
        PendingIntent mainIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, YourApplication.getInstance().downloadService.mainIntent, 0);
        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(YourApplication.getInstance())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Starting Service")
                .setContentText("Initiating...")
                .setContentIntent(mainIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build();
        startForeground(mNotificationId, notification);
        if (YourApplication.getInstance().downloadService.videoDownloader != null) {
            YourApplication.getInstance().downloadService.startDonwloadThread(YourApplication.getInstance().downloadService.videoDownloader);
        } else {
            stopSelf();
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DummyActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

The DummyActivity:-

```
public class DummyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        finish();
    }
}
```

The AndroidManifest entry for DummyActivity :-

```
            <activity
            android:name=".downloader.DummyActivity"
            android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="false"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
```

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: @comoran i did a foreground service and not killed. i dont know, why you doing this. But, Thanks for share knowledge! good job!!

Answer (score 0):

You are startinf Service with NOT_STICKY param. 
You should return **START_STICKY** inside onStartCommand()

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int sid){
        this.sid = sid;
        PendingIntent mainIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, VuclipPrime.mainIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(VuclipPrime.getInstance())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Downloading Video")
                .setContentText("Initiating...")
                .setContentIntent(mainIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build();
        startForeground(mNotificationId, notification);
        if (VideoDownloadManager.currentVideoDownloadTask != null) {
            VideoDownloadManager.currentVideoDownloadTask.start();
        } else {
            stopSelf();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

From documentation:

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

- START_STICKY: the system will try to start the service again when
  it's killed.
- START_NO_STICKY: the system wont care about if the
  service is killed.

Comment: Also you might want to run the service in an [own process](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#proc).

Comment: Are you calling to stopSelf() when the service is stopped or destroyed? Or even in your onStartCommand's "if". Maybe it could be the problem.

Comment: I am calling stopSelf() if there is nothing to download

Comment: Maybe you can have a look to AlarmMaganer. Is another way to check executions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20305630/1820599

Comment: @GPuschka running the service in its own process restarts the app

Comment: @adalPaRi I don't need to restart the service, just need it to contine even after the app has been killed

Comment: Please refer this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458540/foreground-service-getting-killed-when-app-is-swiped-off

Answer (score 0):

Android discontinues process if it's not listed as protected app when process is in sleep mode. Go to Settings->Protected Apps->Select your app and enable as protected app.